# How to fix String index out of range: -1

Tags: java, string

I have been working on a generating password method that will change every "S" to $.

Note I take the phrase in from another class and it will always be greater than 8 characters

```
    String key;
    String store;
    key = phrase.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    phrase = key + phrase.substring(1,phrase.length());
    System.out.println(phrase);
    System.out.println(phrase.length());
    for(int i = phrase.length(); i>0; i--) {
        int sKey = phrase.indexOf('S');
        store = "$" + phrase.substring(sKey+1,phrase.length());
        phrase =phrase.substring(0,sKey)+store;
        System.out.print(phrase);
    }
}
```

However I always get this error afterwards

```
Exception in thread "main" Te$taaaajava.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at edu.ilstu.Security.generatePassword(Security.java:15)
    at edu.ilstu.SecurityApp.main(SecurityApp.java:57)
```

Comment: What does `phrase.indexOf('S')` return when there is no `S` in the substring?

Comment: An index out of bounds exception is caused by one thing, which is using an index that is out of bounds of the list/array/collection you're iterating. Use the debugger to figure out where your code is exceeding the limits (below the valid starting index or above the maximum index).

Comment: if (sKey != -1) before changing store will fix your issue

Answer (score 2):

Index out of range exception value of -1 means the requested symbol, in this case, S, is not found.

Comment: Thank you kept seeing in the debugger this happening but after an hour I thought of making an if statement to catch this to prevent the error.

Answer (score 1):

You take `phrase.indexOf('S')` on a string without checking the return value. If there is no match, the method returns `-1`.  You then use this index as the upper bound of a substring, which crashes the program.

You would want a different algorithm even if you got it correct, if I understand correctly what you want to do.  There is no reason both to search the string for each occurrence of the character you want and also to write a loop decrementing the length by 1.  Also, avoid copying long arrays and strings if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. However, I have found adding an if statement actually fixed this code and stopped the for loop when the index becomes -1

````
    String key;
    String store;
    key = phrase.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    phrase = key + phrase.substring(1,phrase.length());
    for(int i = phrase.length(); i>0; i--) {
            int sKey = phrase.indexOf('S');
            if(sKey >= 0) {
            store = "$" + phrase.substring(sKey+1,phrase.length());
            phrase =phrase.substring(0,sKey)+store;
            }else {
                i=0;
            }
    }```
````